# Getting type of outer object Python

Tags: python, types, parameters, annotations, nested

How do I get the type of an object that contains other data types inside of it?

Example: **[3]**, which is a list into an int, or [int]
How do I get the type of the outer object (the list), and how do I get the type of the inner object (int).

What I'm getting so far when I call type on this code specifically:

```
type([<class 'int'>])
```

I end up getting the same exact thing:

```
[<class 'int'>]
```

instead of just list alone.

I'm working on the .**annotations** inherent function in Python and need to access all the different types of annotations, even if they're nested in each other.

Comment: Can you give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about what you want to do? or the code that you have tried so far?

Comment: This is literally all I want to write: type([<class 'int'>]) to return a type class of list

Answer (score 1):

From what I have understood from the question, you want to know the type of outer element, i.e list, and inner element, i.e int
I think this is what you are looking for. This would return nonetype if list is empty.

```
>>>k=[3]
>>>type(k)
<type 'list'>
>>>type(k[0] if len(k) > 0 else None)
<type 'int'>
```

please correct me if i got the question wrong